# SVN no coge las clases nuevas

Tags: svn

Tengo un proyecto y si creo una clase nueva el SVN no la detecta tengo que abrir el repro browse y arrastrar el archivo forzando asi la subida. sin embargo lo normal seria que hiciera un comit y me aparezaca. Ademas si hago por ejemplo un refactor del nombre me sale que he eliminado e archivo pero no me sale el nuevo con el nombre nuevo. alguna idea como solucionarlo?